# Can someone suggest some reference for a particular kind of infinite series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can someone suggest some reference for the properties of the series $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} f(n, i)$

For example, when can we apply approximations to $f(n, i)$ that only works when $n \to \infty$, such as $(1 + \frac{a}{n})^n = e^a$

This entanglement is quite problematic, because I suppose we can't just change it to $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} f(n, i)$, and apply standard results such as uniform convergence

Comment: The dominated converge and monotone convergence theorems can be useful for series. And their proofs in this setting are comparatively simple.

Comment: You _can_ apply those results. Define $g(n,i) = f(n,i)$ for $i\le n$, $g(n,i)=0$ for $i>n$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^n f(n,i)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty g(n,i)$.

Comment: Wow that's illuminating. Thanks!